# Spring Boot with KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, encryption, amazon-kms

My Spring Boot microservice is running in a Docker container. It requires an encryption key for encrypting the incoming payload. I thought of using AWS KMS for storing the keys. Reading them at runtime, and encrypt the payload.

I was trying to find out the libraries that can be used for accessing the AWS KMS from Spring Boot microservice. Searching on the Google results in below GitHub projects.

- https://github.com/zalando/spring-cloud-config-aws-kms
- https://github.com/kinow/spring-boot-aws-kms-configuration

There is an SDK from AWS as well.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-example-code.html

I am little confused on which one I should use? The two GitHub projects seems to be more open approach than using AWS SDK to me. Also, the "zalando" project was last updated on May 2020... so they appears to be active.

Comment: The Java KMS SDK has been updated [12 times this month so far](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms).  How fresh do you want the library?

Comment: Is there any other criteria that I need to consider for using these libraries?

Comment: The AWS libraries are the platinum reference - created by Amazon for Amazon.  If you ever changed to something besides Spring they would still work.   Without a bit more code it's difficult to tell you but just accessing some KMS keys is unlikely to be very much code in any of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Add the needed [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config/2.2.6.RELEASE).

Create some secrets in AWS as 'other type of secret'.  Name those secrets based on your project.

1. `/secret/application` for properties shared across all services
2. `/secret/{spring.application.name}`  for the properties to look up for this specific service.

The above can be changed via some Spring configuration properties -  [see section 3.3](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-aws.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_secrets_manager)

Then just inject them as you would any other property:

```java
@Value("${verySpecialKey}") 
private String verySpecialKey;
```